# How to avoid the "System.InvalidOperationException: The client projection contains a reference to a constant expression" error?

Tags: c#, rest, linq

I am writing a C# .NET 5 application that will act as a backend for an Angular frontend, providing CRUD APIs. The purpose of the app is managing a flight school.

I am writing the API methods that will return the list of pilots and the single pilot, that is `https://myapp/api/pilots` and `https://myapp/api/pilots/{id}`.

I have three methods here:

1. `GetPilots()` for the complete list
2. `GetPilot(long idPilot)` for the detail
3. an auxiliary method `GetFlightTime(long idPilot)` to return the total flight time of each pilot doing the sum of the flight durations.

**My problem**: the detail method works because I *first* call the auxiliary function and *then* I use the result in the returned viewmodel. But `GetPilots()` doesn't work and returns the error `System.InvalidOperationException: The client projection contains a reference to a constant expression of 'QTBWeb.Models.PilotsRepository' through the instance method 'GetFlightTime'. This could potentially cause a memory leak; consider making the method static so that it does not capture constant in the instance.`

Is this because I am calling the `GetFlightTime` method inside the LINQ expression? I don't understand the *make the method static* suggestion. How can I reformat the code to make it work?

Thanks!

```
   public IEnumerable<PilotViewModel> GetPilots()  // THIS METHOD RETURNS ERROR
    {
        return _context.Pilots
            .Select(pilot => new PilotViewModel
            {
                Id = pilot.Id,
                Name = pilot.Name,
                FlightMinutes = GetFlightTime(pilot.Id)  // THE PROBLEM IS HERE
            })
            .ToList();
    }

    public PilotViewModel GetPilot(long idPilot)  // THIS METHOD WORKS
    {
        var _flightMinutes = GetFlightTime(idPilot);

        return _context.Pilots
            .Select(pilot => new PilotViewModel
            {
                Id = pilot.Id,
                Name = pilot.Name,
                FlightMinutes = _flightMinutes
            })
            .Where(pilot => pilot.Id == idPilot)
            .FirstOrDefault();
    }

    public int GetFlightTime(long idPilot)
    {
        return _context.Flights
            .Where(flight => flight.pilot == idPilot)
            .Select(flight => flight.Duration).Sum();  
    }
```

Comment: Given that `GetFlightTime` is C# code, how do you expect EF to translate it into something which can be executed by your database? You can either 1) Fetch the data you want from the database, and materialise it into a list/etc, *before* running `GetFlightTime`, or 2) Turn `GetFlightTime` into something which can be executed by the database (e.g. by doing a join)

Comment: (Out of those, doing it properly as a join will be significantly more efficient, otherwise you end up with an N+1 problem, where you're doing an extra *query* for each pilot which is returned)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A good way to solve this would be to make sure that your `Pilot` class has a collection of `Flights`, serving as the other side of the one-to-many map you have as `Flight.Pilot`.
You can then use this collection to calculate the sum, without having to query the database for every looped instance of `Pilot`.

Your code would look something like this:

```
public IEnumerable<PilotViewModel> GetPilots()
    {
        return _context.Pilots
            .Include(pilot => pilot.Flights) // Include Flights to join data
            .Select(pilot => new PilotViewModel
            {
                Id = pilot.Id,
                Name = pilot.Name,
                FlightMinutes = pilot.Flights.Sum(flight => flight.Duration)
            });
    }

    public PilotViewModel GetPilot(long idPilot)
    {
        return _context.Pilots
            .Include(pilot => pilot.Flights) // Include Flights to join data
            .Where(pilot => pilot.Id == idPilot) // Notice how we filter first
            .Select(pilot => new PilotViewModel
            {
                Id = pilot.Id,
                Name = pilot.Name,
                FlightMinutes = pilot.Flights.Sum(flight => flight.Duration)
            })
            .FirstOrDefault();
    }
```

Comment: "*Sum() is a LINQ method that, as far as I know, does not translate to SQL*" -- what makes you think that? I'm fairly sure that it's supported

Comment: If you just remove the `.ToList()` in your call chain, I suspect this will be a reasonable answer (although it might well get translated to a sub-query, I'm not sure)

Comment: I could very well be wrong, I've not had the opportunity to actually experiment with this right now. This would mean that we do not require to call `ToList()` before we call `Select()`

Comment: I have edited the post to correct this, thanks for mentioning it

Comment: This solution is simple and elegant and EF Core had actually included the collection of Flights into the model, so this answer solves perfectly my problem. Thank you!!!

Comment: Note you don't actually have to use .Include() in either of these queries, EF will do the join automatically

Answer (score 0):

You must use Eager Execution,means `_context.Pilot.tolist().Select(pilot => new PilotViewModel {Id = pilot.Id, Name = pilot.Name,FlightMinutes = pilot.Flights.Sum(flight => flight.Duration) });`